Is the reference frame defined by the average motion of massive particles in the universe the same as that defined by the CMBR?
Title.
Also, related question: It seems easiest to measure the velocity of stars, but does the average star velocity actually match the overall average mass velocity, including the interstellar and intergalactic media?

What does it mean for the CMBR to define a reference frame? You should specify that.

@controlgroup, probably the one that neutralizes CMB red/blue shift in all directions

@Isaac I think symmetry arguments would dictate the answer to your question in the affirmative

@RC_23 What symmetry?
